# Items not showing up on activity log

Tags: civicase, activities

It appears that, following the last upgrade, items which previously showed on an individuals activity log now don't show up.  A colleague sent out an email which was assigned to a case.  The email shows on the case but not in the colleagues activity list.  This list is used as a record that we can refer to as a quick check if something has been misassigned or that we did remember to do something.  What was the reason for this being changed and is it something we can choose to bring back?

Comment: Hi Gillian - welcome to civicrm stack exchange. Just a note for future posts - it helps both people answering questions - and for other users that find your question (and hopefully the associated answer) if you include the version of civicrm you are using (and often it helps to include whether you are using drupal wordpress etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this was changed recently. I preferred it the old way too, but there was a feeling that it was duplication.
See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12620